# Automating Monitoring of Task Scheduler on remote system

Tags: powershell, automation, scheduled-tasks, monitoring, remote-access

I want to automate monitoring of my scheduled task on a remote server using PowerShell. Like their last run time, next run time, Description etc.

I tried to use `Get-Scheduledtask` and `get-scheduledtaskinfo` but I am not getting any idea of how to connect to a remote server.

Need some suggetion with powershell or anything else will also do. But I don't want to use any tools. Thanks!!

Comment: Get-ScheduledTask has a -computername parameter to specify the computer you want to get the task objects from.

Comment: this is what i use https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Scheduled-tasks-from-3a377294/